# Best way of unobtrusive onload in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What is the best **unobtrusive** way of invoking something after the page is being loaded in plain JavaScript?     Of course in jQuery I would use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

but I am not sure about the most reliable approach in plain js.

Clearly

```
window.onload = ...
```

is not proper solution, because it would overwrite previous declaration.

What I am trying to do is to insert an iframe into a div after the page is loaded, but maybe there are actually better ways of doing it. My plan is to do something like:

```
window.onload = function(divId){
 var div = document.getElementById(divId);
 div.innerHTML = "<iframe src='someUrl' .. >";
}
```

EDIT:
Apologies for not including all necessary details.
The script is not for my website - the idea is to show a part of my site (a form) on external web sites. The priority is to minimize the effort someone has to put to use my code. That is why I would like to keep everything in js file and absolutely nothing in `<script>` - except of `<script src="http://my.website/code.js" />`. If I change URL of an iframe or I would like to add some features, I would like to update the code on all other web sites without asking them to make any changes.
My approach might be wrong - any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: You've commented a couple of times that the script is coming from a different domain. If you think this is significant, put it in your question -- but I don't see any reason it would be significant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//For modern browsers:
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", someFunction, false );

//For IE:
document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", someFunction);

`attachEvent` and `addEventListener` allow you to register more than one event listener for a particular target.
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Also definitly worth looking at how jQuery does it:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js  Search for `bindReady`.

Comment: I cannot require from external sites to use jquery on their site. I need the most generic possible solution

Comment: I don't mean you should use jQuery, just that it's worth studying its code. jQuery has an intelligent, extremely well tested answer to your question. And that answer is to be found between lines 446 and 489.

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.addEventListener` and the events `load` or `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){alert("first handler");});
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){alert("second handler");});
```

`object.addEventListener('event',callback)` will insert an event listener into a queue for that specific object event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener for further information.

For IE5-8 use `window.attachEvent('event',callback)`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx. You can build yourself a little helper function:

```
function addEventHandler(object,szEvent,cbCallback){
    if(typeof(szEvent) !== 'string' || typeof(cbCallback) !== 'function')
        return false;
    if(!!object.addEventListener){ // for IE9+
        return object.addEventListener(szEvent,cbCallback);
    }
    if(!!object.attachEvent){ // for IE <=8
        return object.attachEvent(szEvent,cbCallback);
    }
    return false;
}
addEventHandler(window,'load',function(){alert("first handler");});
addEventHandler(window,'load',function(){alert("second handler");});
```

Note that `DOMContentLoaded` isn't defined in IE lesser 9. If you don't know your recipient's browser use the event `load`.

Comment: seems like this is exactly what i need

Comment: Note that in IE you may need to use attachEvent http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: @mkk: Unless you need to support IE.

Comment: @PaulDixon: IE doesn't support `DOMContentLoaded`, so it doesn't matter whether you use `attachEvent`. IE9 and higher might, but they also support `addEventListener`.

Comment: yes I need to support everything actually. Thanks for try though

Comment: Provided a little helper function. @T.J.Crowder: IE9 supports `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',...)`, it was a feature Microsoft showed in a [testdrive demo](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html). But you're right, the old IE won't understand `addEventListener/DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your script include at the very end of the document, immediately before or after the ending `</body>` tag, e.g.:

```
(content)
(content)
<script src="http://my.website/code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the markup above the script will be accessible via the usual DOM methods ([reference](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)). Obviously, not all ancillary resources (images and such) will be fully loaded yet, but presumably that's why you want to avoid the `window` `load` event (it happens so late).

The only real purpose of `ready`-style events is if you don't control where the script gets included (e.g., libraries) or you need to have something execute *prior* to the page load **and** something else *after* the page load, and you want to avoid having two HTTP requests (e.g., for two different scripts, one before load and one after).

Comment: this is not an option. the script will be loaded from completely different domain.  also this is not unobtrusive method

Comment: Where the script comes from is irrelevant. It might not be an option for you but it's still a valid and sometimes very simple option (for example when you add the script tag to the page footer).

Comment: @mkk: It's no more obtrusive at the end of the document than at the beginning; the claim otherwise is one of the great myths of web authoring (either way, you have to have a `script` tag in the document *somewhere*). Putting it *inline* with the markup, e.g. peppering scripts and/or `onxyz` attributes all of the place, *that's* obtrusive. Separately: It being on a different domain is also irrelevant.

Comment: The thing is that the script will go lets say to 20 sites. As I understood you suggest inserting iframe in inline script, something like <body>...<script>document.getElementById('id').innerHTML (...)</script></body> and then if I decide to change something in the iframe script like url I would have to ask 20 sites to change something on their website. You can treat my script as a "library". Maybe I did not fully understand your approach - you are right that I will ask 20 companies to put <script> but that is why I would like to keep js on my site and make easy extensions/fixes/adjustments

Comment: @mkk: No, I didn't say anything about using an *inline* script. The script tag at the end can refer to your file via `src` just like any other script tag. All the 20 sites have to do is add the script tag, **once**, at the end of the file (rather than at the beginning). Example: http://jsbin.com/ibiken/edit (although the script file in that example is on the same domain, that's not a requirement, I just didn't have another domain handy).

Comment: ok i get it - this might also work. I am just wondering if this solution will cover 100% cases - maybe some web sites will use some kind of strange CMS and it will allow to insert scripts only in <head> ? I am just guessing of course - but if I can do something that would not require placing something in a specific part of the web site, I would prefer such solution. Thanks for your comment

Comment: +1 for the effort, though my final solution is to adopt jQuery's solution