# Javascript function being executed even if its not called

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so I'm fairly new to javascript and right now, I'm experimenting in defining functions and hiding/showing specific elements.

in this simple program that I made, I am trying to show a loading screen while a function is still executing. the problem is, the function that is inside the onlick event handler executes even without clicking the button

```
<body>
<button id="thisbutton" type="button">clickme</button>
<div>
    <p> The download will begin in <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</p>
</div>
<div id="loadss" class="LockOn"></div>

<script>

    document.getElementById("thisbutton").onclick(meow());
    document.onload = rawr();
        function rawr() {
        document.getElementById("loadss").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("loadss").style.display = "none";
        }

        function meow() {
            document.getElementById("loadss").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("loadss").style.display = "block";
            time();
            document.getElementById("loadss").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("loadss").style.display = "none";
        };
        function time() {
            var timeleft = 10;
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
                timeleft--;
                document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
                if (timeleft <= 0)
                    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            }, 1000);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: function meow is being called ??

Comment: yes it does call that function

Comment: if you will use parenthesis () after the function it will be called no matter it is within a click event. you can also use a function without its name or without declaring it separately in JavaScript.

`code`

    document.getElementById("thisbutton").onclick(function(){

document.getElementById("loadss").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("loadss").style.display = "block";
            time();
            document.getElementById("loadss").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("loadss").style.display = "none";
});

`code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, functions are [first-class citizens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function).  This means you can treat them like most variables:

```
function test () { console.log('Hi!'); }

var x = test;
```

And you can execute them by using parentheses on any reference to them:

```
test(); // will execute function test
x(); // will _also_ execute function test
```

Hence, your code:

```
document.getElementById("thisbutton").onclick(meow());
document.onload = rawr();
```

is *executing* the functions `meow` and `rawr`.  You perhaps want to *pass references* to these functions:

```
document.getElementById("thisbutton").onclick(meow);
document.onload = rawr;
```

Comment: thank you for a concise answer about references and method calling. now from what I understand is than on document.onload, it must call the function that is referenced when the document has completed loading. 

I referenced the function rawr to the document.onload but does not execute it after the page has loaded. (although calling with rawr() executes it, I believe that it is a very cheap way to handle this problem)

Comment: The problem is with the way the you are registering the event handler.  This is tricky to explain / understand; try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274530/1136527

Comment: Favor using `addEventListener` over attribute/property-based events like `onclick` and `onload`.  eg: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", meow)` or `document.addEventListener(myDiv, 'click', meow)`

Comment: Also, in case you missed @CertainPerformance's comment, `onload` is not a _function_, but a _property_ - hence `.onload(meow)` should be `.onload = meow` - although I would avoid using `onload` at all.

Comment: I have not missed @certainPerformance's comment and included his answer. thank you for further explaining your answer and giving me more material to read. I have another question though but I guess it would be better to create a new question as the main question is answered

Answer (score 1):

your code

```
document.getElementById("thisbutton").onclick(meow());
```

should be like following

```
document.getElementById("thisbutton").onclick = meow;
```

notice i did not call the `meow` function and onclick is not a function but a property.

also your code

```
document.onload = rawr;
```

should be

```
document.onload = rawr;
```

when you use parentheses then the function gets called.

Comment: why down vote this? tell me so that i can improve it.

Comment: `onclick` is not a function (initially), it is a property that can be assigned to.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes yes yes, i corrected that mistake. thank you very much.