# How to separate HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am styding JS right now.
I need to get the HTML and JS as many as possible getting seperated.
So that everything is in a HTML and a loose JS file.
How do I seperate this:

```js
   <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Inzendopgave 242S2 - F.W.J.C. de Graaff
        <script async src="script.js"></script>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Inzendopgave 242S2 - F.W.J.C. de Graaff</h2><br/>
    <p>Voer uw bedragen in:<br/></p>
    <input type="text" id="invoer1">
    <script>
    //Maak een globale variabele:
    const bedrag = document.getElementById("invoer1");
        //Voeg er een event-listener aan toe:
        bedrag.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            //Alleen triggeren als de Enter-toets wordt gedrukt:
            if (event.key === "Enter") {
                //Dan voer het volgende script uit:
                //Maar een Block variabele en geef deze de waarde van de ingevoerde string:
                let uitkomst = document.getElementById("afvoer2").innerHTML;
                //Tel de invoer bij de uitkomst op en maak van de strings integers (getallen):
                document.getElementById("afvoer2").innerHTML = parseInt(uitkomst) + parseInt(bedrag.value);
                //Maak invoerveld weer leeg:        
                bedrag.value = "";
            //Sluit alle nog openstaande regels/tags:
            }
        }
    )
    //Puntkomma om de event-listener te sluiten:
    ;
    </script>
    <h3>Uw ingevoerde totaal:</h3><br/>
    <div id="afvoer2">0</div>


    </body>
    </html>   
</code>
```

When I place everything that is inside the script-tags and save that to a seperate js-file, the event-listener doesn't work anymore... Well is it possible at all to separate it?

Greetings,
--Tech

Comment: Did you check was the js file loaded to the document? You should also show the code which doesn't work instead of a working snippet.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274374/best-way-of-unobtrusive-onload-in-plain-javascript

Comment: It looks like your `<script>` tag was mistakenly placed inside the `<title>` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place all your Javascript code in seperate `myScriptFile.js` file. Include the script at the end of your `<body>` tag in your HTML like so:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src='/path/to/myScriptFile.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use inline javascript the document is rendering so if you reference an element by ID that existed before the script tag the element has likely already been registered which is why you can attach an event listener to it.  When you link an external javascript file it will typically be loaded before the document is rendered and therefore the element doesn't exist yet.  To resolve this problem simply have your code which attaches event listeners to the document elements run after the document has loaded.

See related issue: [best way of unobtrusive onload in plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274374/best-way-of-unobtrusive-onload-in-plain-javascript)